# Python/FFMPEG command line issues

Tags: python, ffmpeg, webcam, alsa, v4l2

I have a problem with running an FFMPEG command from within a Python script. When I run the following command from the terminal, I can stream video and audio from my attached webcam (Logitech C310) and output to file "out.avi" without any errors.

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -itsoffset 00:00:00 -f video4linux2 -s 1280x720 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 out.avi
```

When I run the same command in a Python script below,

```
def call_command(command):
    subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '))

call_command("ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -itsoffset 00:00:00 -f video4linux2 -s 1280x720 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 out.avi")
```

it gives me the error:

```
Input #0, alsa, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1317762562.695397, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
[video4linux2 @ 0x165eb10]Cannot find a proper format for codec_id 0, pix_fmt -1.
/dev/video0: Input/output error
```

Could anyone shed some light on what could be going on here? I've tried using os.system() as well as subprocess.call() and it gives me the same errors. I'm not sure where to start on what could be going wrong here. I tried searching for the "video4linux2 Cannot find a proper format for codec_id 0, pix_fmt -1" error, but couldn't find anything consistent.

I've also tried putting the "ffmpeg -f..." command in a shell script "test.sh", and giving it executable permissions. I then open terminal, and run "./test.sh", and it works. When I try calling the command "./test.sh" from within my Python script, I'm left with the original error as before. This is the Python command I tried with the test.sh script:

```
subprocess.call(["./test.sh"])
```

Comment: your invocation in python may point to a different build of ffmpeg in a different path. try `ffmpeg -version` and check if they output the same thing.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested, and they're both pointing to the same version, FFmpeg 0.6.2-4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1

Thanks, at least that issue is ruled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. In my Python script, I'm using OpenCV to display these frames as well as record them using ffmpeg. There is a conflict when trying to run the ffmpeg command and display them on the screen using OpenCV.

More specifically, when creating a OpenCV CreateCameraCapture object:

```
from opencv.cv import *  
from opencv.highgui import *

capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0) #conflict with ffmpeg/v4l2 occurs here
```

Commenting out that line of code fixes my problem. There aren't any issues with Python and executing commands.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try running Popen with shell=True argument.

```
subproc = subprocess.popen(command.split(' '), shell=True)
```

Comment: FFmpeg has a lot of black magic in it.  It is quite possible that it treats the command line differently if hooked up to stdin/stdout pipes versus a true terminal.  I also wonder about the use of two `-i` arguments.

Comment: Already tried it. Doesn't work. Script exits, spits out the FFmpeg version number, it's libraries, and this:

    Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'

Comment: Could you try with os.system() instead? Something like 

os.system(r'ffmpeg.exe -i "%s" "%s"'%(path+f,path+outf))

Just to make it clear that it's not Python's fault.

Answer (score 0):

`Shell =True` is not a good option in most cases.
It do not works if you need pipe as output.
Use

```
pipe_stdin=True
```

It solves the problem for me.